# is that necessary to implement Command in mvvm pattern for android

Tags: android, mvvm, command

I'm trying to build an Android app with MVVM pattern.
I had read [Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484.aspx) to learn about MVVM. It mentions that ViewModel implements properties and commands, so they can interact with each other via data binding, commands. And almost all blogs about MVVM mentions Command, but none of them implement the Command.
There is two kind of them

```
<Button
    ...
    app:onClick="@{mvvm.onClick}"/>

public class ViewModel {
    public void onClick(View view){
    }
}
```

another

```
<Button
    ...
    app:onClick="@{view.onClick}"/>

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onClick(View view){
        viewModel.onClick();
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public void onClick(){
    }
}
```

Which of them is right? If both wrong, how to implement Command in MVVM pattern for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented few android projects by using MVVM. Most of the online resources suggest to use your first approach, so I started with it i.e. layout.xml will hold a reference to viewModel. But sooner I faced few challenges with such implementation.

In MVVM, view holds a reference to viewModel, but viewModel does not hold any reference to view, so it is loosely coupled and can be easily tested. Let say my onclick button need to insert a row and perform some animation. The problem here is viewModel does not have any reference to the layout resource hence it cannot do any layout related functions.

To solve this akward situation , I have changed to second approach i.e. layout.xml holds a reference to view and view holds a reference to viewModel. In the view.onClick event, I will do any layout related coding first, then call my viewModel.onClick to perform some core logic, or connect to model if needed.

layout.xml --> view --> viewModel --> model

In my opinion, there is no right or wrong for this question. It is based on your situation and personal preference.